# How to add a new Activity type to the Task work item in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I would like to do exactly what is being proposed in this question, but instead of VSTS, I'd like to do it in on a On-Premise TFS(2018):

> ["Is it possible to add a new Activity type on the Task work item in
>   VSTS and, if so, how can I do it? Thanks!"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48645881/2912011)

I've followed the instructions [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/update-customized-process-template?view=tfs-2018) to export and modify my custom project template. However when I follow [the instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade?view=tfs-2018)(Step 5 of the original instructions) I get stuck at the "Configure Features" step, that does not appear in my implementation of TFS (Yes, my user account is part of "Project Collection Administrators"):
[image]
[image]

I'm sort of confused, there are people that claim this [can't be done](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48645881/2912011). In fact it's even stated in the process page:

> "Changes you make to a process template will only apply to new team
>   projects. They will not affect existing team projects."

But the instructions clearly indicate that it can be, I just done see the "Configure features" link? The instructions indicate that the use case is after a TFS update, but if I just changed my custom template, how would I enable this, so I can implement my changes in the custom template?

Comment: I can help clarify: "Configure Features" is for **after an upgrade**, when the process template needs to be upgraded. It has nothing to do with what you're trying to do. After you modify a process template in the XML based model, you have to reimport it with `witadmin`, which is part of Visual Studio / Team Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below ways to achieve that:

- ## [Import, export, and manage work item types with `witadmin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018)

  1. **Export** the specific work item type definition file (`Task` in your scenario). Run command prompt with administrator, if you are
     using VS 2017, then `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
     Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team
     Explorer`

     `witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ProjectName
     /f:C:\temp\MyTask.xml /n:Task`
  2. **Edit** the exported WIT definition file (`xml`) with text editor, add a new Activity Type (e.g.: `TestActivity0727`in below
     sample)
     like below:

     [image]
  3. **Save** the file and **import** to TFS with `witadmin` command:

     `witadmin importwitd /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ProjectName
     /f:C:\temp\MyTask.xml /n:Task`
  4. Refresh the page, now the new activity should be worked in `Task`
     work item.
- ## Edit with **TFS Process Template Editor**, reference below screenshot:

  For VS 2017, install the extension [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor)

  For VS 2015, just install [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation
  Server 2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)

[image]

Comment: It's work, thank. But the `importwitd` don't accept the parameter `/n` : `TF212000: /n is not a valid argument for this command.`