# Cannot Create MultiValueControl in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs-workitem, multivalue

I am updating existing Workitem Template to have a new field that should be "MultiLineControl". Below is what all i did.
1) Changed WorkItem template as

```
     <FIELD name="IssueOwner" refname="test.IssueOwner" type="String" reportable="dimension" >
      <HELPTEXT>Issue Owner</HELPTEXT>
        <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true">
        <LISTITEM value="test1" />
        <LISTITEM value="test2" />
        <LISTITEM value="test3" />      
        </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
      </FIELD>

 <Control FieldName="test.IssueOwner" Type="FieldControl"  PreferredType="MultiValueControl" Label="Issue Owner" LabelPosition="Left" />
```

2) Installed extension First i tried from below location under "Install control on Web Access"
    https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/multivaluelist-control-in-tfs-work-item-tracking/
   But then the extension is deprecated for TFS 2017

So then I installed 
    https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control

But still my field is Simple dropdown. Not sure what i am missing. Can someone plz help

Update 1) I also tried stuff from [Entension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-multivalue-control/blob/master/xmldetails.md) but it doesn't effect any change. in my Work Item export I have two section  in FORM. Layout and WebLayout. The link talks abt changing WebLayout. But how to change Layout as thats what my TFS load when i use it on explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on TFS 2017 (`Version 15.117.27414.0`), everything works as expected.
Please follow below steps to do that:

1. Install [Multivalue control](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control) extension.
2. Export the specific WIT with [witadmin tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=azure-devops-2019) (you can also use the `TFS Process Template Editor`if you are using Visual Studio 2015 or 2017, reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51568514/7466674) for details. ) :
   `witadmin exportwitd /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project /n:TypeName /f:FileName`
3. Open the exported `xml` file with text editor and add an `Extensiontag` to make the control available to the work item form.

   ```
       <Extensions>
           <Extension Id="ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control" />
       </Extensions>
   ```

   [image]
4. Add your customized field:

   ```
    <FIELD name="IssueOwner" refname="test.IssueOwner" type="String" reportable="dimension" >
     <HELPTEXT>Issue Owner</HELPTEXT>
       <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true">
       <LISTITEM value="test1" />
       <LISTITEM value="test2" />
       <LISTITEM value="test3" />      
       </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
     </FIELD>
   ```
5. Add the `ControlContribution tag` for your Multivalue control. This
   example adds it to the "Status" group.

   ```
       <Group Label="Status">
         <Control Label="Reason" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.Reason" />
         <ControlContribution Label="IssueOwner" Id="ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control.multivalue-form-control">
               <Inputs>
                   <Input Id="FieldName" Value="test.IssueOwner" />
               </Inputs>
         </ControlContribution>                  
       </Group>
   ```
6. Import the modified `xml` file to your project:

   `witadmin importwitd /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project /n:TypeName /f:FileName`
7. Check the result:

[image]

Comment: @user3182464 Have you resolved the issue by the solution? Any update here?

Comment: yes it worked for me too after I enable new Form in TFS 2017. Thanks