# Add MyActivity to Activity Picklist for Capacity Planning in Azure Devops Services

Tags: azure, azure-devops

[image]

How can I add a new activity type to this list while doing capacity planning in Azure Devops?

Please note that I am **NOT** using on-prem hosted version rather using the cloud services

Also, please don't direct me to this question as it only addresses how to add a custom field to replace activity field in a work item only. [How to add a new Activity type to the Task work item in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645881/how-to-add-a-new-activity-type-to-the-task-work-item-in-vsts)

My question is strictly for Capacity Planning picklist for cloud hosted Azure Devops

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the process that your project uses.

1. Make sure your process is editable. Here is an article on [how to customize your process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=azure-devops)
2. Once you can edit your process, open the issue type your process uses for Iteration backlog (Tasks usually). Same should work for Requirement backlog (User Story for Agile, for example)
3. Add existing field called 'Activity' to one of your work item pages
4. Now you should be able to edit this field: add, remove whatever you need in the list of possible values

After you save the list of possible values for Activity field, the drop down you refering to should have the combined list (items from Requirement backlog and Iteration backlog levels, i.e. from User Stories and Tasks, for example).

Answer (score -1):

The reason the workaround given in that other question is to create a new field is because **you can't change the existing field**. Thus, the answer is "you can't add a new activity type to the capacity planning view".

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But I have seen an organization who has customized this and were using Azure Devops Services (Not Server). I am now wondering how did they do it.

Comment: @Daniel, -1 Your answer may be out of date, Georgy's answer above adds new activity types to the Boards - Sprints - Capacity view, and the work details side pane.