# Is there a way to use a inherited Activity type in capacity tracker

Tags: azure-devops

Based on below conversation you cannot directly add a a new activity to capacity tracker but if we created a custom Activity field would that custom activity be available in the capacity tracker? Would out of box report be able to use this custom Activity to create reports?

[Add MyActivity to Activity Picklist for Capacity Planning in Azure Devops Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906749/add-myactivity-to-activity-picklist-for-capacity-planning-in-azure-devops-servic)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use a inherited Activity type in capacity tracker

I am afraid we still can not use this custom Activity in capacity tracker, even if we use a inherited Activity type.

That because the a inherited Activity type is use to the **Work item types** rather than Sprints/Azure Devops. So we could not modify the system field-custom Activity in capacity tracker.

Besides, there is a user voice that you can vote and follow, and this user voice is already on the roadmap, I believe it will meet with us soon:

[Customize values in system fields such as Team Capacity, Priority, etc.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365553/vsts-custom-team-capacity-activity-as-well-as-cust.html)

Hope this helps.